# How to assign the function keys in web application in ASP.Net with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the web application and i want to use the function keys(f1,f2,...) in my web application as we can do in the windows application.

How can i do this?

Thanks,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: Web browser is a windows application and chooses not to pass certain keystrokes to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it your self:

http://www.ryancooper.com/resources/keycode.asp

Still remember that I don't think the actual behavior will change (so I you press F1 you might detect that but in IE still the help file will open). So take inot acount the usefullness/useability of your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it if you write a plugin like ActiveX, Flash or Silverlight.  Depending on the install the user will still have to grant permission to run executables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a crazy idea.

The F keys already have functions native to the browser, in IE for example:

- F1 – opens the browser’s Help page
- F3 – opens the browser’s Find function
- F4 – drops down the browser’s address bar history
- F5 – refresh page
- F6 – puts focus into the address bar
- F7 – allows you to turn carat browsing off/on (whatever that is!)
- F10 – goes to the File menu
- F11 – toggles full screen
- F12 – toggles the Developer Tools

Even if you detect keystrokes the browser will still perform its native function.